# KDB: select first n rows from each group

Tags: kdb, q-lang

How can I extract the first n rows from each group?  For example: for table
bb: `` ([]sym:(4#`a),(5#`b);val: til 9) ``

```
  sym   val
  -------------
  a     0
  a     1
  a     2
  a     3
  b     4
  b     5
  b     6
  b     7
  b     8
```

How can I select the first 2 rows of each group by sym?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Can use fby:

```
q)select from bb where ({x in 2#x};i) fby sym
sym val
-------
a   0
a   1
b   4
b   5
```

Comment: No problem. However be aware that this solution (along with the other one posted) assumes your table is in-memory. For on-disk queries it would obviously be a bit different

Comment: Is it possible to update the query so that it'll 1) only return the first 100 records if a group has more than 100 records 2) return all the records if the number of records for a given group is less than 100.  Something like select [100] from ...

Comment: Found one solution like this: select from bb where ({x in min[100,count[x]]}#x) fby sym

Comment: The original answer already does this! For example: 
select from ([]sym:`a`b`b`b;val:1 2 3 4) where ({x in 2#x};i) fby sym

Comment: returns all the rows for a as there are less than 2, returns only two rows of b when there are more than 2

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
q)select from t where i in raze exec 2#i by sym from t
sym val
-------
a   0
a   1
b   4
b   5
```

Comment: Thanks. This one works but the fby solution above seems more intuitive to me. ;-)

Comment: I do agree since my solution will have to scan the table twice :D